Configure Azure DevOps Server on premises as IIS Web App under the default WebSite rather than on a new Web Site?
I am evaluating the DevOps Express that should be installed on a web server of the company intranet where other web applications are already installed.
The web applications respond to URL:

https://hostServerName.domain.com/App1/etc
https://hostServerName.domain.com/App2/etc

It would be great if DevOps was installed and configured on IIS responding to the URL:

https://hostServerName.domain.com/DevOps/etc

rather than:

https://hostServerName.domain.com:8080/etc

This is because:

by default the installation involves the creation of a new "web site" that CANNOT be added as "application" under to the default one;
finally, to avoid binding conflicts in the use of the same protocol + any ip + standard port, I am forced to use a new port not in use ... eg 8080.

Maybe I did it wrong but I also tried unsuccessfully to:

delete the new Web site "Azure DevOps Server";
circumvent the previous need by manually creating the reference to the two necessary web applications: \ (in ..\Web Services and "queue". Both app associated with the application pool created with the DevOps installation;

it throws an exception to be interpreted: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0 ... HRESULT: 0x80131040".
I'm thinking of trying using (not knowing the outcome yet) the URL rewrite of clients request as:
https://hostServerName.domain.com/DevOps/etc
Any help is appreciated, thanks anyway

I found a solution that seems to be working as expected.
Briefly, after the default installation of DevOps Express, from IIS I:

deleted the Web Site composed of the two applications: "DevOps" and "queue";
created a new web application, "DevOps", under the default web site, then according to the initial installation scheme I added "queue" under "DevOps".
set the Basic Authentication on the "DevOps" web application.


The error I reported in my previous attempt (as stated in my help
request) "Could not load file or assembly.... HRESULT: 0x80131040",
was due to a dirty installation in the default application associated
with the default web site, I have now deleted.

Now, step by step:

Here the IIS state from defaut DevOps installation
After deleting the Web Site installed with default setup:
I delete "Azure DevOps Server", note "DevOps" app must use his Application Pool and so also "queue"
At least enable Basic Authentication:
Setting basic authentication

Finally, there was no need to use a new port (8080) and the application will be reachable from:

https://hostServerName.domain.com//DevOps

as in the style of other applications hosted on the Web Server managed with IIS.
Hope this will help someone,
of course considerations and suggestions are wellcome
